# Is there a way to get the create table statement for a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the create table statement for a migration. So instead of just run rake db:migrate, if you can write something to invoke a migration and instead of running up or down, be able to run it but instead of getting the table created, you could just get the create table statement instead.

Something like Createfootable.up and be able to specific if I want the create table statement for SQLite or MySQL, etc.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure I get you. If you want to see that, just open up the corresponding file.

Comment: I'm not clear why you'd want this but then I don't know everything :) ... you can change your production / development / test databases via config > locals > database.yml ... would that meet your needs?

Comment: Might help: http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/rails_and_slony.html#referrer=simononsoftware.com (Look for text `desc "Run migrations through a monkey patch"`)

Comment: Ah, right... like Tony Hopkinson says, you can see the migrations in db > migrate ... the file names all start with a timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

These are 2 separate questions:

1. Can I generate a query string (or set of query strings) from a migration?
2. Can I select which adapter to use when running migrations (or generating queries from them)?

The short answer to both of these is "yes, you can".

```
class CreateFoosTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :foo do |t|
      t.int :bar
      t.string :baz
    end
  end
end
```

To answer the second question first, you can switch your adapter by changing the ActiveRecord configuration used to establish a connection:

```
mysql_config = {
  adapter:  "mysql",
  host:     "localhost",
  username: "myuser",
  password: "mypass",
  database: "somedatabase"
}
sqlite_config = {
  adapter:  "sqlite",
  database: "path/to/dbfile"      
}

require "db/migrate/20130711000000_create_foos_table.rb"
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(mysql_config)
CreateFoosTable.up      # run against mysql
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(sqlite_config)
CreateFoosTable.up      # run against sqlite
```

Now to your first question, how can I generate the sql instead of actually executing it?

The simplest way is to override the `execute` method to output whatever is passed in:

```
# replace 'SQLiteAdapter' with AbstractMysqlAdapter to do the same for MySQL
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter.class_eval do  
  def execute(sql, name=nil)
    puts sql
  end
end
```

Running `CreateFoosTable.up` should now output the SQL to console.  If you want to capture the SQL strings to some variable, replace `puts sql` with whatever logic suits your needs.

Note that while overriding `execute` will work for `create_table`, it won't do the job properly for modifying existing tables.  This is because `execute` is needed to determine the existing schema before generating the modification SQL.  In this case, you're better off aliasing and checking if the query starts with `CREATE`, `ALTER`, or `DROP` before proceeding.

Comment: I don't know whether I need to know all that, but I LIKE knowing it.